# How do I get my retention policy to work and can I test it the same day?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow, retention

I set a retention policy on a list. The retention policy is supposed to trigger a workflow the day after an item has been created. I waited a day for it to work and t did not. Today I try to test to see if the retention policy works at all. So I removed the old stage from my retention policy and created a new stage which is supposed to move an item to the recycle bin the day it has been created. That did not work as well. Is there any way to test a retention policy the day has been created? Also can you think of any reason why a retention policy would not work. I'm trying to trigger a workflow every day. I know I can use workflow looping to achieve this but I have been burned by long-running workflows in the past.

Comment: Retention policies are handled by a timer job in SharePoint which if I remember it correctly runs on a weekly basis. Do you have access to the servers?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Christoffer No I don't have access to the servers, unfortunately. After the first day the retention policy runs if I set it to ocurr daily will it run daily? Also how can I find out what day during the week the retention policy runs?

Comment: No, the job still only runs once a week if not configured otherwise, I’m not sure if that would work thought. You’ll have to ask your adminstrator when the job ” Information management policy” runs. You could always create a simple workflow that send you and email when it runs but at it’s worse it could make you wait a whole week.

Comment: Just to clarify, even if my retention policy is to trigger a workflow a day after an item has been created and then to reoccur every day. The retention policy will still only run once a week?

Comment: Yes, I belive so. As long as the timer job is set to run each 7 days, your workflow would only trigger once a week if you would not add a pause operation to your workflow but I personally do not recommend long running workflows.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Christoffer I guess I can't use a retention policy. I agree I should not use a long-running workflow either that is why I wanted to avoid using the pause operation in a workflow. But I don't know any other alternative to making sure a workflow runs on a specific date. Hence why I wanted to use a retention policy but that seems to be a no go.